# How to print over previous text rather than below it in python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.6

this may be a weird question and English is not my first language so I'll try to word it as best as I can. Also, keep in mind that I'm very, very new to programming. I've looked for this question quite a bit and can't seem to find the answer, either because it doesn't exist, or much more likely because I don't know how to word it properly.

How do I replace the text being currently displayed (being printed) rather than add the text after (below) it.

Let me explain. I've created a simple program that executes automated mouse and keyboard actions using pyautogui. What I'm trying to do is not even really necessary for my program to function, but I'm trying to learn programming so I want to make my program just a little more fun to use. So instead of having different scripts for each automated actions or to simply ask a question and then input a number for each script, I tried to emulate sort of a user interface (again, I'm a total beginner at both Python and programming in general, so it's incredibly basic). What I've tried to do was create a simple menu where the options are displayed and the user can type the number associated with the script they want to execute.

The only issue is that I find the end result to not be visually interesting. When something happens, the new text or, eventually the new contextual menu, doesn't replace the current one. It just prints below the older one.

Here is what the menu looks like:

```
**************************************************************************
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                 What script would you like to execute?                 *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                 1. Option 1                                            *
*                 2. Option 2                                            *
*                 3. Option 3                                            *
*                                                                        *
*                 * Type "quit" to shut down                             *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
**************************************************************************
```

Now let's imagine that Option 1 leads to another menu where you can choose Option 1.1, 1.2, etc. How do I make the new menu replace the current one rather than just print next to it?

Here is the part of the code I'm talking about:

```
def launch():
print('''

**************************************************************************
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                 What script would you like to execute?                 *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                 1. Create an opportunity                               *
*                 2. Show sales dashboard                                *
*                 3. Show pipeline dashboard                             *
*                                                                        *
*                 * Type "quit" to shut down                             *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
**************************************************************************

''')
answer = input("Enter your choice now.\n\n")
if answer == "1":
    print('Launching "Show sales dashboard ".')
    time.sleep(1)
    create_opp_move()

elif answer == "2":
    print('Launching "Create an opportunity".')
    time.sleep(1)
    show_sales()
elif answer == "3":
    print('Launching "Show pipeline dashboard".')
    time.sleep(1)
    show_pipeline()
elif answer == "quit":
    print("You have chosen to quit this program.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Program shutting down in...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    raise SystemExit
else:
    print("Answer is invalid. Please enter a valid statement.")
    time.sleep(2)
    launch()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the screen using

```
print('\033c')
```

Then rebuild the screen.

Comment: Ok so that didn't work, BUT it did help me quite a bit. By giving me that answer you also helped me find the proper wording for my question "clear the screen". I've looked for it and found that I can do:


import os
os.system('cls')


and it does what I wanted. This is perfect. Thank you anyway!